# Code splitting for global styles in nextjs

Tags: webpack, next.js, sass

I'm creating a website using nextjs, where we have option for css module imports, but that creates randomly generated classes in the webpage, like: `"header_navigation_fae3ff"` but I wanted a clean css class as I define in the css file like: `"header_navigation"` and also module option for writing css for each page in its own directory. So, I used sass `@use` method to import all the styles written in other location into `global.scss` like this:

#### File directory

```bash
├───app
│   globals.scss
│   layout.tsx
│   page.tsx
│
└───dashboard
    ├───page.tsx
    └───_dashboard.scss
```

#### layout.tsx

```js
import "./globals.scss";
...
```

#### globals.scss

```scss
@use "dashboard/dashboard";
...
```

#### dashboard/page.tsx

```js
export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <aside>data</aside>
      <section className="dashboard-main">everything else</section>
      <nav>navigation links</nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### _dashboard.scss

```scss
.dashboard-main {
  padding-left: 4px;
  border-left: 4px solid aqua;
}

.not-used {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 4px solid darkblue;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

But I don't know if there is code splitting for the css files for each page after writing css in another file then importing this in the global css file. Basically, is whole `global.css` file is requested in the first request, or it is splitted into chunks so only required styles were fetch.
Because when I'm refreshing the page `'/dashboard'` then in network tab there is a css file with the class named `.not-used`, which was created to check if it is loading or not, because it isn't used in the dashboard page.

Or if there is a better way to keep css classes clean in the browser, please recommend. I don't want to use tailwind.